# Login screen is rotated

Tags: 11.10, login-screen, lightdm

When I turn on the computer, the login screen is rotated. But when I log in to my account, the screen is normal. 
I have an ATI graphics card on an AMD laptop. The settings is normal for two user accounts, so I don't know why it is rotated only in the login screen. Please help me.

Comment: Is your monitor rotated (eg. would it considered be 3:4 or 9:16)? Perhaps the proprietary driver settings aren't kicking in until after login?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand very well what you are asking me, but I think my monitor is not rotated because in the display window there are options only for 4:3 and 16:9  settings

Comment: I could not edit that last comment. My monitor IS NOT ROTATED

Comment: Is it a new issue?

Comment: I think this is a new issue, because I have searched on the internet and it seems to be that no one has had this problem before